# jQuery selector after append not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-selectors

I am trying to append dynamic data to my page.

I have

`<div id="container"> ... </div>`

and want to add content to it

`$('#container').append('<p id="myid" style="display:none">Test</p>');`

Then I try to do

`$('#myid').fadeIn();`

and it doesn't work. No errors or anything are printed. The append works but the fadeIn doesn't do anything as I think selector is not able to get the newly added element.

I know that if I wanted to have dynamic event listener for the newly created element, I would need to use [jQuery's on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) but in this case I am not sure how to re-use the selector.

Answer (score 0):

You need apostrophes around #container here:

```
$(#container)
```

Comment: The apostrophes around container was missing (my bad). I rushed to post this question. Please read the question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/prollygeek/8f7Zp/

should have used

```
$('#container')
```

Comment: That's not the point here, that was my mistake and I fixed it here. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: @PetrosP please check my fiddle !

Comment: Ok it works now, not sure what was wrong with my original code but it started to work. Now I regret asking this question as it was so obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
$('#container').find('#myid').fadeIn();
```